# Change <button> with <input> with an onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change an element with another element with the help of a "onclick()" function, but I have no idea how to do it... I only know how to create new elements, but that's not what I need...

Let's say I have a  element, that I want to change into an  element that will appear on the same spot where the  element was.

I know how to "hide" and "show" elements in jQuery, and it would fit perfectly here, but the problem is that the CSS display: none; style can be easily turned off in the browser.

Comment: there is no PHP onclick() function. php is server side.

Comment: to do this kind of thing you would have to do AJAX to pass back the button, but most of this would be done with JavaScript.

Comment: you say its a problem that people can manually go in with developer tools and change css to show elements you want to be hidden? so whatever you are hiding, for whatever reason, you want to be secure?

Comment: It makes almost no sense at all to change a `<button>` to a `<input>` - if you have styling issues, use different CSS classes.

Comment: I don't think PHP can help you with this. This seems like something for Javascript/jQuery. Also can we see your code so we have something to work off of? Last comment is I think you should be more clear about what you are trying to do because <button> and <input> can be interchangeable depending on how you code it so the solution you are looking for might not be the ideal solution.

Comment: You could generate the correct input on the server based on a URL parameter.

Comment: Kris, perhaps you can show some code samples of what you have and what you want it to be. It's hard to tell what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to make a <button>Add</button> change into <input placeholder="Input here..." /> with an onclick(). And I've totaly mistaken the javascript onclick() with the PHP <form><submit>. That's what you get for coding all day. So let me chage the question: how to change the element using javascript?

Comment: The question is completely unrelated to PHP. It is about JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: Thank you guys for all your replies! Now I see where I've done a mistake... It should have been refered to javascript, and not PHP. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it easily with jQuery.

```
<button id="button1">Button</button>
```

then jQuery JS

```
$(function(){
    $('#button1').click(function () {
        $(this).replaceWith('<input type="text" />');
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you! I've did a mistake in the question... should have been related to javascript, and not PHP

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with JQuery, can use the remove or empty command to delete the current tag, then use append or prepend to add the new tag?